# 2 Left joins put together multiplying the results. But it shouldn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I am building a chat site and for presenting the chats to the audiences, I have 3 Dropdownlists - Sports (Default is All Sports), Day/Month/Year, Users online/Total Users.

Now, if by default all sports is selected and I pick 1 month and Total users, the expected result should be

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT roo.[Sports], 
                roo.[Name], 
                COUNT(DISTINCT chu.ChatUserLogId) AS TotalUsers, 
                COUNT(DISTINCT liu.[LoggedInUserID]) AS UserOnline

 FROM Room AS roo 

 LEFT JOIN LoggedInUser AS liu ON roo.RoomID = liu.RoomID 
 LEFT JOIN ChatUserLog  AS chu ON roo.RoomID = chu.RoomID 
               AND chu.LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) 

 GROUP BY roo.[Sports], roo.[Name]   
 ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

One person suggested that with my method I am actually multiplying the row because of the two joins & so I need to aggregate first, then join.

So in the end, I tried this query too

```
with agg_ChatUserLog as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_tot from ChatUserLog WHERE LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) group by RoomId),                                            

       agg_LoggedInUser as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_logged from LoggedInUser group by RoomId)

select Sports, Name, cnt_user_tot, cnt_user_logged from Room r 

       left outer join agg_ChatUserLog acu on acu.RoomId = r.RoomId 

       left outer join agg_LoggedInUser alu on alu.RoomId = r.RoomId;
```

But this is also multiplying the results.

Where am I making the mistake in both the query? Thanks in advance and have a nice day ahead.

SAMPLE DATA IS:

```
Chatroom name   Total Users   Online users               

Basketball
Roomname27          32              5
Roomname11          15              3
Roomname32           8              1 

Football
Roomname5           63              12
Roomname18          44               7
Roomname4           15               2
```

Comment: Second method looks good. Add sample data and your second query result we will check

Comment: In the question not in comment

Comment: @Prdp I have added the samples in the question for your reference. Thanks and looking forward for your help.

Comment: That is sample output.

Comment: I have added all the Table schema earlier in the question itself. Do you need anything more? Plz tell me if you need to solve this issue with the 2nd query in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try another syntax :

```
select Sports, 
    Name, 
    coalesce(
        ( 
            select count(distinct C.ChatUserLogId) 
            from ChatUserLog as C
            where C.RoomId = R.RoomId 
              and C.LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) 
        ), 
    0) AS TotalUsers,
    coalesce(
        (
            select count(distinct D.LoggedInUserID)
            from LoggedInUser as D
            where D.RoomId = R.RoomId 
        ),
    0) AS UserOnline
from Room R
```

with this syntax, you will never have more results than number of roomname.
but you also have room whitout audience

Comment: This is how we coded at first... But it's making the case even worse. Aggregating first and then SELECTing data makes only the Sport's chatrooms repeated when there are any ONLINE USERS. But in your query(as well what we tried first), even though there is NO ONLINE USERs, its simply repeating all the Sport's chatrooms.ONLINE USERS vs TOTAL USERS table get multiplied. Could you guess why there is this error? Thanks

Comment: I guess the issue with the "GROUP BY" items too... "with agg_ChatUserLog as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_tot from ChatUserLog WHERE LoggedInTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) group by RoomId), agg_LoggedInUser as (select RoomId, count(*) as cnt_user_logged from LoggedInUser group by RoomId) select Sports, Name, cnt_user_tot, cnt_user_logged from Room r left outer join agg_ChatUserLog acu on acu.RoomId = r.RoomId left outer join agg_LoggedInUser alu on alu.RoomId = r.RoomId GROUP BY Sports, cnt_user_tot ORDER BY cnt_user_tot DESC"